# A variable that I've initialized is undefined when I try to use it on the next line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm developing a web application that is heavily using Javascript and jQuery.

I basically create an `app` object when the web page loads and call the `init()` method in the footer.

```
var app = new App();
app.init();
```

These are the first lines of code in the `init()` method.

```
// Load up the index
app.loadIndex();

alert(hashtag_index);
```

These are a few lines of the `loadIndex()` method.

```
hashtag_index  = [];

// Load the Topic JSON File
$.ajax({
    url : './data/index.json',

    type : 'GET',

    dataType : 'json',

    .
    .
    .

    // If the file loading is successful, save the index data
    success : function(data){

    var raw_index = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        raw_index.push(data[key]);
    });

    // Add the hashtag object to global hashtag_index
    hashtag_index = raw_index;

    }
});
```

Basically what the `loadIndex()` method does is loads a json file which is about 135kb and load the data as an object to the `hashtag_index` variable. The `hashtag_index` variable is defined global, so it's accessible globally.

The variable hashtag index have 8 different `Object` arrays. But during when I try to `alert()` the variable, the variable isn't initialized yet.

But `alert()` only returns an blank message. When I return this as an message:

```
alert(typeof(hashtag_index))
```

I get `undefined` as the message.

But now I'm sure the variable is loaded because, when I access the variable via Google Chrome's console, I can see the variable is loaded up and all the objects are in there.

The only was I solved the problem was by using this line of code:

```
// Load up the index
app.loadIndex();

setTimeout( function(){

    alert(hashtag_index);

}, 500);
```

By making javascript sleep 500 ms, I've given enough time for it to load up.

Of course I've tried the following solutions but none of them succeeded:

**Solution 1:** (Goes into an infinite loop)

```
// Load up the index
app.loadIndex();

while(!hashtag_index.length > 0) {

    continue;

};

alert(hashtag_index);
```

**Solution 2:** (Goes into an infinite loop)

```
// Load up the index
app.loadIndex();

while(hashtag_index.length == 0) {

    continue;

};

alert(hashtag_index);
```

**Solution 3:** (Goes into an infinite loop)

```
// Load up the index
app.loadIndex();

while(typeof hashtag_index === 'undefined') {

    continue;

};

alert(hashtag_index);
```

**Solution 4:*** (Goes into an infinite loop)

```
// Load up the index
app.loadIndex();


while(typeof hashtag_index == null) {

    continue;

};

alert(hashtag_index);
```

Now my question is how can I solve this problem definitely without causing any future problems. I've tried to tackle the problem with the previous solutions, but none of them have succeeded properly.

Comment: What is you App constructor look like??

Comment: will  !hashtag_index.length > 0   work !!

Comment: Well the data you request from the server is most likely requested by you with an ajax request. Thats why you see the data when using a `setTimeout` (if you receive the data within the `500` ms). The loops won't work because `js` is single threaded and the request (if it is an async one) is done when the current script is finished (so after the loop).

Comment: Yes, I request the data using AJAX. Currently I'm trying to use @jason-p method to resolve it right now.

Comment: @sebastien I only def a few variables, which one of them is `hashtag_index`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `app.loadIndex();` method uses ajax, which is async. So the `alert(hashtag_index);` executes before the ajax call has completed and the result is processed.

Change your code to use a callback, or (my preference) have `app.loadIndex();` return a promise object.

Here's how you could implement a promise:

```
var loadIndex = function() {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        //...
        success: function(result) {
            // do whatever
            def.resolve();
        }
        //...
    });   

    return def.promise();
};
```

....

```
// Load up the index
app.loadIndex().done(function() {
    alert(hashtag_index);
});
```

You may need to extend this to have `init()` return a promise or accept a "finished" callback as well, depending on your usage.

Comment: You're right about me using an ajax request. But I've implemented the callback function as you described and the variable is still undefined. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your answer. Even though your solution didn't solve the problem, you showed me to the right direction for the problem. I've basically called all of the functions inside the callback function from now on.